# chrome based browser "feature" - how to get original functionality back?

Tags: google-chrome, rss, prompt

[image]

If you try to visit the default rss feed for any recently updated wordpress site in the chrome browser you ALWAYS get this annoying prompt for "Which service should be used for viewing?". This **did not** used to happen in chrome. This **does not** happen in other major browsers. How can I *correct* this in chrome to just show me the parsed xml like it used to?

PS the example page you see in the background is http://wordpress.com/feed - as soon as you try to visit that page in chrome you should see this prompt as well.

Comment: Hmm... visiting that link for me makes a file called "download" download on my computer. Suspicious.

Comment: @Erty that's even more odd than what I'm experiencing. What version of chrome are you on? I'm on OSX Lion - Chrome 21.0.1180.57 w/no plugins

Comment: 21.0.1180.75 m on Windows 7, Flashblock and Adblock Plus.

Comment: I now have the same behavior in Google Chrome ver 21.0.1180.75 m

Comment: I have the same problem! What on earth is going on? Did you ever get a response?

Comment: Fixed! I've marked the answer below. thx @JLND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered "Feed Intent Viewer" which is a Chrome extension that basically brings back the old functionality.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oceapojkdgeophkjdijkpbjifdnfimdh

Answer (score 1):

I am using chrome Version 21.0.1180.79 on ubuntu and having the same request to download issue on such safe websites as sciencefriday.com.  I have submitted the problem to chrome. -fingers crossed for a patch-

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution after many research (because it's really annoying...)

Download and install the new Beta version of chrome: it's all fixed